# Keycloak Page has expired in Forget Password

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am getting **Page has expired** page on trying to do multiple clicks on Forgot Password after adding username.

Flow is as follows:
- On clicking "Forgot Password?" from Login screen.
- It redirects to "Forgot Your Password?" screen, where it accepts username and
allow us to submit the form.
- Shows "Page has expired" screen with two options:-

To restart the login process Click here.
To continue the login process Click here.

There are 2 issues:
1. Not sure why its taking user to Page has expired page.
2. The redirected page has CSS issues. Refer attached screenshot.

Is there anything wrong with my Keycloak configuration? I am using 6.0.1 version of keycloak

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Advice: Use always new version of keycloak (currently 10.x)

I guess it is related with token nature (expired). As I see your reset-password template is broken. There are some crucial variables and conditions in this template.